# Issue with .bind('click', function...) in IE6-8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, bind

I'm having a problem with the following code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd. MM yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    altField: "#date"
}).bind('click', function() {
    var userDate = $('#date').val();
    $('.date2').html(userDate);
});​
```

The .bind just does not work in IE6-8, any other browser works just fine.

What i'm doing: When clicking on any element within the #datepicker, it pushes the selected date into a field with the ID 'date'. Then i check the value of this field and push the date into a span, with the class date2.

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Ok, so I was able to fixed it. The correct code works fine in ALL browsers now.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  dateFormat: 'dd. MM yy',
  firstDay: 1,
  altField: "#date",
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $('.dateOutput').fadeIn(250);
    $('.date2').html(dateText)
  }
});
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: The datepicker part is working? Including pushing the value into the other field? How have you determined that `bind` isn't working, just by not seeing the result in the span, or have you walked through with [a debugger](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) or done a console.log (IE8 with dev tools open) or (shudder) `alert`?

Comment: The datepicker is working, yes. It is pushing the value into the field. Works fine in IE9. When adding an alert within the bind-function it is not triggered neither.

Comment: `@Andreas`: Useful info (I'd edit it into the question). And very, very strange. Can you replicate the problem on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: `@Andreas`: Please move your update into an answer, and then accept it when the site lets yoU (a couple of days from now).

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain it's [DOM is not ready for JavaScript processing](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)  issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd. MM yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        altField: "#date"
    }).bind('click', function() {
        var userDate = $('#date').val();
        $('.date2').html(userDate);
    });
});​
```

Comment: It is within a function ( function enableDatepicker(){ ... } ). Sorry i didn't mention that.

Comment: And if this were the case, it would affect other browsers as well. @Andreas: It being within another function doesn't *necessarily* mean it's not the DOM ready thing, if your other function is called before DOM ready. :-) But if your script is at the end of the page, or if you're already waiting on an event (`ready`, `load`, whatever) then this isn't it (and it would affect other browsers).